# CLient authentication does not work properly (with certificate)

Tags: node.js

I want to check (dynamically via config file) a client certificate, but this does not work properly.

If I don't have a certificate I can still access the site sometimes.

this is my code

Server:

```js
const { createServer } = require("https")

// config.ssl.client_crt = true or false

createServer({
      cert: readFileSync(config.ssl.crt_file),
      key: readFileSync(config.ssl.key_file),
      requestCert: config.ssl.client_crt,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      ca: readFileSync(config.ssl.ca_file),
},app).listen(config.port)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    authenticator.req_check(req, config.ssl.client_crt, function(ok) {
        if (! ok) {
            return res.send("nope")
        }

        return res.send("ok")
    })
});
```

authenticator:

```js
module.exports = {
    req_check(req, client_crt, cb) {
        if (client_crt && req.client.authorized == false) { // <-- Pay attention!
            return cb(false)

        } else {
            return cb(true)
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but when I write it this way the value of `req.client.authorized` is sometimes ignored

```js
if (client_crt && ! req.client.authorized) {
    return cb(false)
}
```

in my opinion it is the same, or am i wrong?

of course i don't want anyone to access the site without a certificate, so i need your help to make the check absolutely reliable

Comment: Please be more precise than "is sometimes ignored": Describe how you make a request that passes the `req_check` although it should not.

Comment: I make a get request via browser (chrome/firefox) without client certificate. The expected response should be "nope". But this is not always the case. I would say at random intervals I get "ok" which should not be the case

Comment: Do you close all browser windows before you make the request without certificate? I ask because browsers remember a certificate that you used once and use it again for later connections.

Comment: The browsers do not even have the correct one installed.

Comment: So there is no valid client certfifkat for this website and still the request is accepted. How can this be?

Comment: It should not matter how many requests I make, all should be rejected as long as no certificate is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want authorization by client certificate to be enforced, you must set `rejectUnauthorized: true`.

Also, certificates should be checked already when an HTTPS connection is set up, even *before* the first HTTPS request goes over that connection:

```js
var server = https.createServer({
  cert: readFileSync(config.ssl.crt_file),
  key: readFileSync(config.ssl.key_file),
  requestCert: config.ssl.client_crt,
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  ca: readFileSync(config.ssl.ca_file),
}, app)
.listen(config.port, function() {
  server.on("secureConnection", function(socket) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var cert = socket.getPeerCertificate();
    if (!socket.authorized ||
        now < new Date(cert.valid_from).getTime() ||
        now > new Date(cert.valid_to).getTime())
      socket.end();
 });
});
```